# Does MySQLFabric support mysql replication semi synchronous ( 5.7 version) when failover happens?

Tags: mysql, mysql-fabric

Semi synchronous Replication can be established in Mysql Server 5.7.

If in a cluster or HA group of 5.7 mysql servers is used in latest MySQL Fabric, when secondary becomes primary does the secondary automatically get the semi synchronous settings?

The reason for this is, for semi synchronous to happen, we need to manually set up settings on the master and its slaves. But when the master fails, do we need to do the same thing manually or through scripts?

Or does the Mysql fabric supports it?

Answer (score 0):

You can install both the master and slave plugins to both machines and have both master and slave semi-sync permanently enabled.

When the master is demoted it will attempt to connect to the new master on the semi-sync thread.

It works pretty seamlessly.